# Difference between seq(1,5) vs seq(1:5) in R

Tags: r

Can any one please help me understand the difference between the calling of below function in "R":

```
a <- seq(1,5) # output: 1,2,3,4,5
b <- seq(1:5) # output: 1,2,3,4,5
```

In both scenarios, "1,5" & "1:5" the sequence function returns the output.

Please help me understand it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is documented on the manual page for `seq` although it can be a bit tricky. The first warning is in the Details: "The interpretation of unnamed arguments of `seq` and `seq.int` is *not* standard, and it is recommended always to name the arguments when programming."

If you provide a single value, you get a sequence up to that value beginning with 1:

```
seq(5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Two values get treated as from, to:

```
seq(1, 5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

If you provide a vector, e.g 1:5 or 6:10, you get a sequence from 1 to the length of the vector since the only argument in `seq` that takes a vector is `along.with`. The values in the vector are irrelevant:

```
seq(1:5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
seq(6:10)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: So even if the argument is named `seq(from = 6:10)` it still overrides it and considers it as `along.with` ?

Comment: Yes because the `from` argument does not accept a vector. The alternative would be for it to just use the first value in the vector and return 1:6. It you want to create multiple sequences you would use something like `lappy(6:10, seq)`.

Comment: That is strange since it doesn't even return any warning like for other functions, Eg - `rep(1:3, each = 6:10)`

Comment: Thank you dcarlson, this would really helpful. looks like I need to understand the grammar/syntax of seq(...) function in detail for better understanding / usage in day-to-day programming. Thanks once again.